# How to use the new Code Manager in the new Omniture Interface

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am confused within the new Omniture Interface for a small thing. I am trying to Generate SiteCatalyst JavaScript Code for my site.

Here is what I did.

- Created Report Suites from  Report Suite Manager.
- and got confused how to generate code for my site.

See the old interface made it very clear to create code for my site by selecting a Report Suite as explained [here](http://webanalyticsland.com/sitecatalyst-implementation/implement-sitecatalyst-in-5-minutes).

But how to generate code by selecting a Report Suite in the new interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the code generation is or if it even exists any longer. Have you considered using the tag manager?

It's in the Admin home under "Tag Management". You can download the site snippet from there. You will see all the code in your container at that point. You have to set variables a little differently when you use the tag manager at that point but there is plenty of documentation around it.

Answer (score 0):

**Code Manager**
Code manager lets you download data collection code for web and mobile platforms.
Admin tools > Code Manager.
After you download the library, you must configure the code to send data to the correct tracking server and report suite.

**Tag Manager**
TagManager is the standard method for deployment of Adobe Marketing Cloud tags.Tag Manager 2.0 is the latest one available.
*TagManager lets you:*

Deploy Marketing Cloud products and Genesis integrations though a single hosted JavaScript file.
Manage tags and configuration in a secure administrative interface.
Test changes and quickly roll back to previous versions.
Use existing SiteCatalyst tags to implement TagManager without a complex deployment process.
Deploy third-party tags.

**Dynamic Tag Manager**
Adobe acquire Satellite and it is now DTM.It is the future of implementation.
Visit the link [DTM](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/dtm/index.html#Getting_Started_with_Dynamic_Tag_Management)

Answer (score 0):

The old Code Manager is still there, just a bit hidden. If you go into the interface for Code Manager, just under that table is this text. It brings you to the old Code Manager:

```
To view the legacy code manager or download AppMeasurement libraries for BlackBerry, Windows Phone 7, or Symbian click here.
```

In future the world is expected to go with Tag Management and when you have time it is recommended that you implement that.

Thanks C.